# Как вызвать метод, когда mapGetters вернул значение. Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Задача такая - в App.vue (корневом компоненте) 1 раз загружаются данные - currentUser.
В компонентах мы получаем эти данные из vuex через mapGetters в computed.
И когда они загрузились - можно выполнить другой метод - в каждом компоненте - разный. Т.е нужно отследить их наличие.
Я пробовал сделать так:

```
watch: {
    currentUser: function() {
        if(this.currentUser) this.getAllUsersFromGroup(this.currentUser.groupInvite);
    }
},
```

Проблема в следующем - этот код отслеживает изменение currentUser, а не наличие. А мне нужно отследить момент, когда currentUser уже есть в хранилищи. Как это сделать?

Comment: может добавить булевый флаг, который при создании компонента равен `false`, а при первой успешной проверки меняется на `true`, и если он равен `true`, то повторно обработчик не вызывать

Comment: Лучше всего начальные данные, без которых приложение не будет нормально работать получать до рендеринга. А уже потом запускать процедуру `$mount`. Вариант со слежкой за значением тоже нормальный, но в случае, если таких моментов будет много и в разных компонентах, получится куча дублирующегося кода.